# Unable execute external process from CGI C++

Tags: c++, web, cgi

I have a problem about call external process from CGI C++.
I want to run a macro (*.xls file) from CGI code directly but it's not working. I just see the EXCEL.exe process existing in the task manager (CGI run on APACHE). When I have run it on the command line then it worked.

```
system("start excel \"C:\Temp\91a3e34f-e2e4-442f-af32-4a38bef95a8e\FrfmMod91a3e34f-e2e4-442f-af32-4a38bef95a8e.xls\"");
```

Does anybody help me?